# How to make global keyboard hook for key combinations?

Tags: c#, winforms, hook, keyboard-hook

I'm using [it](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook) to make global keyboard hook. There are such lines :

```
gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.A);
gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.B);
```

to register hooked hotkeys. How to modify that solution to make hook for combination, for example A+B, but not single A or B?

Comment: Don't use a global keyboard hook for hotkeys. Use RegisterHotkey whenever possible. It trivially supports multi key combinations, but only if all but one key are modifier keys(control, alt, windows, shift), but I've seen no sane application that uses multi key hotkeys that don't use this convention.

Comment: I need global hook, application should catch hotkeys from tray

Comment: `RegisterHotkey` creates global hotkeys. So unless you have really strange requirements, it's a much better fit than a keyboard hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard solution for global hotkeys is the `RegisterHotkey` API. It supports hotkeys with modifiers (Control, Shift, Alt, Windows) out of the box, and doesn't suffer from the global side effects of a hook.

Comment: HotKeyManager.RegisterHotKey(Keys.A, KeyModifiers.Alt); - what to change to make it ctrl + alt + a?

Comment: I think you need `KeyModifiers.Alt | KeyModifiers.Control`